# Set content of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following structure.

```
<div>
<p>Hello World !!</p>
</div>
<iframe id="myiframe" src='myiframeContent.html'></iframe>
```

and I have the following JavaScript variable with `content`:

```
var s ="<html><head></head><body><div>Test_Div</div></body></html>";
```

How can I change the content of iframe with id `myiframe` with variable `s`?

I tried:

```
$("#myiframe").html(s);
```

Which giving me a very unusual return, it changes all the content of Current page to `VAR S`
Ex : styles,background etc..

How can I set the content of an iframe with a variable that contains `HTML`?

The content of variable `s` follows:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>{page_name}</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="{page_meta_tags}" />
    <script src="/1.js"></script>
    <script src="/2.js"></script>
 <style>
   h2{
 
 color:red;} 

 h1{
 color:red;}

 body{
     
 background-color:#f0eded;
 color:74f503;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 background:url({getUrl});}
  </style> 
  </head>
   
  <body>
    yahoo
    <div style="float:right">{pagecomment}</div>
    <div id="blogstart" style="">
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      {nextPrevPagination}
      {blog} 
      {nextPrevPagination}
    </div>
    <p>My Page Name : {page_name}</p><br/>
    <p>Name of this template</p><br/>
    <p>Date started this page : {page_date}</p><br/>
    <label>Address</label>
    <textarea>{page_address}</textarea>
    
    <span>Country : {page_country} State :{page_state}</span>
    <p>page City : {page_city} Page Pincode {page_pincode}</p>
    <a href="mailto:{page_email}">Email me</a>
    {page_bio_title} and {page_bio_desc}
    <img src="{page_profile}" />
    {page_avatar}
    <p>Contact me : {page_mobile} , {page_landline} </p>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/{page_facebook_user}">I am on Facebook</a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/{page_twitter_user}"></a>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

After applying this variable to the iframe I got like this  [inspected through firebug]
Note that it doesn't have `BODY` ,`Head` tag, but the above one [var s] has a `BODY` tag.

```
<html>  
  
    <title>{page_name}</title>
    <meta content="{page_meta_tags}" name="keywords">
    
    
 <style>
   h2{
 
 color:red;} 

 h1{
 color:red;}

 body{
     
 background-color:#f0eded;
 color:74f503;
 font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
 background:url({url});}
  </style> 
  
    yahoo
    <div style="float: right;">{pagecomment}</div>
    <div style="" id="blogstart">
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      {nextPrevPagination}
      {blog} 
      {nextPrevPagination}
    </div>
    <p>My Page Name : {page_name}</p><br>
    <p>Name of this template</p><br>
    <p>Date started this page : {page_date}</p><br>
    <label>Address</label>
    <textarea>{page_address}</textarea>
    
    <span>Country : {page_country} State :{page_state}</span>
    <p>page City : {page_city} Page Pincode {page_pincode}</p>
    <a href="mailto:{page_email}">Email me</a>
    {page_bio_title} and {page_bio_desc}
    <img src="{page_profile}">
    {page_avatar}
    <p>Contact me : {page_mobile} , {page_landline} </p>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/{page_facebook_user}">I am on Facebook</a>
    <a href="http://www.twitter.com/{page_twitter_user}"></a>
  </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4614850/508702

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10418644/471696 , which also has a better answer than this one.

Comment: Note that HTML5 introduced a new parameter allowing to inject HTML automatically: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp **The only problem is the browser compatibility...**

Comment: @JamesM.Greene is it possible to mark as duplicate if the other question came after this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [putting html inside an iframe (using javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620881/putting-html-inside-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Comment: This answer provides a much cleaner solution IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16557787/1217025

Comment: possible duplicate of [set innerHTML of an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050380/set-innerhtml-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I managed to do it with

```
var html_string= "content";
document.getElementById('output_iframe1').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(html_string);
```

Comment: That works great once you make locals and LocalS the same case.

Comment: No, but I never really looked for one.

Comment: @See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418644/creating-an-iframe-with-given-html-dynamically/10433550#10433550

Comment: This method will give you alert boxes with crazy widths. `The web page at data:text/html;charset=utf-8,<html> <head> <title>{page_name}</title> <meta name="keywords" content="{page_meta_tags}" /> <script src="/1.js"></script> <script src="/2.js"></script> <style> h2{................................................. says:` . Your visitors can't read the content of such alert boxes. And they have to use ESC to close the alert box.

Comment: Is there any way to preserve origin of the document in iframe? If there are any hypertext links in "html_string", then they are resolved localy to main window?

Comment: Relevant answer to manage encoding of `data:text/html`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106476/using-javascripts-atob-to-decode-base64-doesnt-properly-decode-utf-8-strings

Comment: @MitjaGustin injecting a `<base>` tag into the head of your html might work https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: There is something like zillion posts around showing something similar but using encodeURI instead of escape, and that is just plain WRONG. This is the only solution working when you inject a body with background color for some reason on chrome at least. THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 30):

Use the "contents" function:

```
$('#some-id').contents().find('html').html("some-html")
```

Relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fDFca/

Comment: Its not working ,it updating the HTML only ,but there is no BODY tag,how can i fix this ?

Comment: The body tag seems to be inserted just fine. See the updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/fDFca/1/

Comment: `<iframe id="test">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>` ITS FROM UR JSFIDDLE ,inspected through firebug,how its happen ??

Comment: Please don't shout at me. It's the way Firefox/Firebug/whatever displays stuff on a page. Try it with Chrome and you'll see it shows the Body tag just fine.

Comment: ahhh no brother...its not shouting ,but my English is very poor,and it makes me dirty.its ok i managed it with `SRC`,passing data to the `SRC` with `escape`

Comment: Note if your iframes are generated from the JS rather than static, you'll want to set the src...src='javascript:void(0)' Otherwise, it will write in your content, then attempt to load the src (even if there isn't any) and leave you with a blank iframe.

Answer (score 26):

### Unified Solution:

In order to work on all modern browsers, you will need two steps:

1. Add `javascript:void(0);` as `src` attribute for the iframe element. Otherwise the content will be overriden by the empty `src` on Firefox.

   ```
   <iframe src="javascript:void(0);"></iframe>
   ```
2. Programatically change the content of the inner `html` element.

   ```js
   $(iframeSelector).contents().find('html').html(htmlContent);
   ```

### Credits:

> Step 1 from comment ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240101/set-content-of-iframe#comment20993503_8240158)) by @susan
>
> Step 2 from solutions ([link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240147/2621216), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240158/2621216)) by @erimerturk and @x10

Comment: just tried this, in IE11 the "javascript:void(0);" value resulted in a DNS error page being displayed in the initial iframe. I replaced it with "about:blank" and it worked.

Comment: this solution fixed the issue I had in Firefox, but it broke Google Chrome, any idea how to make it work in both?

Answer (score 26):

I needed to reuse the same iframe and replace the content each time. I've tried a few ways and this worked for me:

```
// Set the iframe's src to about:blank so that it conforms to the same-origin policy 
iframeElement.src = "about:blank";

// Set the iframe's new HTML
iframeElement.contentWindow.document.open();
iframeElement.contentWindow.document.write(newHTML);
iframeElement.contentWindow.document.close();
```

Here it is as a function:

```
function replaceIframeContent(iframeElement, newHTML)
{
    iframeElement.src = "about:blank";
    iframeElement.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframeElement.contentWindow.document.write(newHTML);
    iframeElement.contentWindow.document.close();
}
```

Comment: `src="about:blank"` not work with safari 10.1 checked at 2018-08-09

Comment: By far the best vanilla JS solution.

Comment: Your method does works however you just keep replacing the html css not javascript that means any function event is defined it will be defined until you reload the iframe or whole page

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Best solution yet. Even WebFlow uses it too! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You want to be using the iframe's `srcdoc` attribute for that ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc)).

```
var html_string = "<html><body><h1>My epic iframe</p></body></html>";
document.querySelector('iframe').srcdoc = html_string;
```

The nice thing about using this method over for example Red's method listed on this page, is that iframe contents added with `srcdoc` are seen as the same-origin. That way can continue to manipulate and access the iframe with JavaScript if you wish.

Answer (score 9):

```
$('#myiframe').contents().find('html').html(s);
```

you can check from here http://jsfiddle.net/Y9beh/

Answer (score 6):

Using [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

```
var s ="<html><head></head><body><div>Test_Div</div></body></html>";
var iframe = document.getElementById("myiframe");
var blob = new Blob([s], {type: "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Works great and probably best answer by far because with this method we can render javascript without duplicating events and functions again and again

Answer (score 4):

Why not use

```
$iframe.load(function () {
    var $body = $('body', $iframe.get(0).contentWindow.document);
    $body.html(contentDiv);
});
```

instead of timer ?

Answer (score 2):

You need -

```
var $frame = $('myiframe');
    setTimeout( function() {
            var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
            var $body = $('body',doc);
            $body.html('<div>Test_Div</div>');
    }, 1 );
```

Code taken from - [putting html inside an iframe (using javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620881/putting-html-inside-an-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an html content containg script tag to iframe, you have access to the iframe you created with:

```
$(iframeElement).contentWindow.document
```

so you can set innerHTML of any element in this.

*But*, for script tag, you should create and append an script tag, like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13122011/4718434