# How can I display a non-styled HTML page inside another page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm gathering HTML from a HTML-editor and save in my database. I want to display this data to the user, but I don't know how to do this without the HTML-text being affected by the styling of my page.

Are there any cool libraries around which can help me with this, or is there a very simple way using only HTML tags and/or javascript?

Comment: Did you consider putting it into an `iframe`?

Comment: Oh wow.. yes that works. Thank you. You can post an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably simply stuffing your HTML into an `iframe`.

Have a look at this question if you want to set it as HTML: [Set content of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240101/set-content-of-iframe) .

But I typically simply accept that the contents of the `iframe` are loaded using a separate request.