# How to set HTML content into an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have a HTML string

```html
<html>
  <body>Hello world</body>
</html>
```

and I want to set it to an iframe with JavaScript. I am trying to set the HTML like this:

```js
contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

or

```js
contentDocument.body.innerHTML
```

or

```js
document.body.innerHTML
```

but IE gives "Access is denied." or "Object does not support this property or method." or "Invalid final element to the action." errors.

Here is my full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_1.7.0.min.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var htmlString = "<html><body>Hello world</body></html>";
        var myIFrame = document.getElementById('iframe1');
        // open needed line commentary
        //myIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = htmlString;
        //myIFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = htmlString;
        //myIFrame.document.body.innerHTML = htmlString;
        //myIFrame.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML = htmlString;
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is iframe:
      <br>
      <iframe id="iframe1">
      <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
      </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you not load a page it works very well? why you want to use a string to load? let me know

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You could use:

```
document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.write("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>");
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yu6a/1), which works in all major browsers.

Note that instead of `contentDocument.write` you should use `contentWindow.document.write`: this makes it work in IE7 as well.

Comment: note, if you are reading and writing in and out iframe, you will need to write document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.write("<html><body></body></html>");
to have empty string reading like this
var iframe_html = document.getElementById('iframe_exe_uploader').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;

Comment: I needed to use open/close to get it working in chrome: 
iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

Comment: If you don't want to append, you can do it with `document.getElementById('output_iframe1').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(html_string);`
[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8322025/1717828).

Answer (score 27):

```
var htmlString="<body>Hello world</body>";
var myIFrame = document.getElementById('iframe1');
myIFrame.src="javascript:'"+htmlString+"'";
```

With html5 you'll be able to use the [srcdoc attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Answer (score 9):

The `innerHTML` is a bit tricky especially in IE, where elements like `thead` are read-only and cause a lot of trouble.

Based on the documentation on msdn you might try `documentMode` which provides a `innerHTML` property.

```
myIFrame = myIFrame.contentWindow ||
    myIFrame.contentDocument.document ||
    myIFrame.contentDocument;
myIFrame.document.open();
myIFrame.document.write('Your HTML Code');
myIFrame.document.close();
```

this might only work in IE.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533897(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 5):

In 2023, the correct answer to this problem is to use the `srcdoc` attribute of the `<iframe>` element. I can be done straight in your HTML file or with javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('iframe').srcdoc = "<html><body>Hello world!</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `document.documentElement.innerHTML`. But do know that everything in the page will be replaced even the script that does that.

For an iframe it would be like this `myIFrame.contentWindow.document.documentElement.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I use this code ie say this error: "Invalid final element to the action."

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with 'origin' with the answers here. This is how it's work for me:

```
const frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
frame1.name = 'frame1';
//not have to set this style,just for demo
frame1.style.position = 'absolute';
frame1.style.height = '800px';
frame1.style.top = '100px';
frame1.style.left = '100px';
frame1.style.background = 'white';

document.body.appendChild(frame1);
const frameDoc =
  frame1.contentWindow || frame1.contentDocument.document || 
  frame1.contentDocument;

frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title><body>Hello world</body></html>');
frameDoc.document.close();
```

Answer (score -4):

try it:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('body').append("Hello world");
});
```

update:

```
$(function(){
    $('iframe').load(function() {
        $(this).contents().find('body').append("Hello world");
    }); 
})
```

Comment: An answer using vanilla JS was expected, this example uses jQuery.