# How to add JavaScript code into existing iFrame using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to add a JavaScript snippet into an existing iFrame in the page using jQuery. I have the following code...

Code:

```
content = "<script>" + js_code + "</script>";

$('#iframe_id').contents().find('body').append(content);
```

But somehow this is not working. I checked some of the existing/related answers, and it seems jQuery does not quite recognize the script tags as...script tags. The iFrame is in the same domain/same port/same host, so there is no issue about cross-site scripting etc. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post ALL relevant code.

Comment: Yes...the content iFrame belongs to me, basically the same domain

Comment: @Gandalf Is the snippet embedded within markup (`<script>...</script>`) or in an separate `.js` file?

Comment: this snippet will be inside (script) tags only...

Comment: interesting.. what about to try this: `frames[0].window.$ = frames[0].window.jQuery = window.$;`

Comment: thanks...but it is not working.

Comment: is the iframe in the same domain as your main page?

Comment: yes...same domain...same port

Answer (score 31):

The problem is that the HTML parser gets confused if your script contains the closing script tag in it (`</script>`) and it closes the script tag prematurely.

The solution is to escape the `/` in `"<\/script>"`. This works because strings in JavaScript, (and some other languages), any invalid [escape sequences](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml) are just ignored, so `"\l"` is treated as `"l"`, and `"\/"` is treated as `"/"`. The HTML parser, however, doesn't use a backslash to escape them so it doesn't get confused (credits to https://stackoverflow.com/users/405681/keaukraine).

```
var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)<\/script>";
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
```

*Original solution*

**Break up that closing tag** so you don't mess up the HTML parser. The other solutions on this page work because they never have the string `</script>` in their code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALpjZ/2/)):

```
var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)<";
scriptTag +=  "/script>";
console.log(scriptTag);
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
```

Or ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwx24Lo0/)):

```
var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)<"+"/script>";
$("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(scriptTag);
```

Comment: Just escape slash: `var scriptTag = "<script>alert(1)<\/script>";` - http://jsfiddle.net/tLHn5/

Comment: @keaukraine That's an awesome technique, never seen it before since there's no need to escape forward slashes. I'm wondering if that behavior is specified though.

Comment: escaping the slash worked perfectly. I put my script tags straight into the src with no issues

Answer (score 8):

```
function putScriptInIframes(script, scriptId) {

   var $iframes = $('iframe');
   $iframes.each(function () {
        var thisDoc = this.contentWindow.document;
        if ( ! thisDoc.getElementById(scriptID)) {
            var scriptObj = thisDoc.createElement("script");
            scriptObj.type = "text/javascript";
            scriptObj.id = scriptId;
            scriptObj.innerHTML = script;
            thisDoc.body.appendChild(scriptObj);
        }
    });
}
```

This was the simplest way I could make it work.

Answer (score 5):

```
var script = "alert('hello world');";
$('#iframe').contents().find('body').append($('<script>').html(script))
```

works in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALpjZ/)

Comment: Care to explain what the difference is? I see it works, but don't understand why

Comment: I believe the difference is the same as the difference between the `text()` method and the `html()` method in jQuery. if you are appending a string, it might not be evaluated as html

Comment: then it must have to do with the script tags specifically.

Comment: @JuanMendes It's not entirely clear why the original didn't work, but guessing the snippet is in a `<script>` element, where mentioning `</script>` would close the element rather than keep as a `String` value. This avoids mentioning it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski That's correct, I added an answer explaining it as you typed this comment.

Comment: this seems to be working only for small javascript functions. For example if the "script" variable contains a full javascript file, this process is not working...not sure why.

Comment: If you need to load a full javascript file, you should probably use `getScript()` to load it into the frame.

Comment: Hi Neil, I don't want to add a JS file. The 'script' variable will always be a JavaScript snippet...however, it can be anything from a JS to jQuery snippet and can be anywhere between a simple function to a 300 line JS code.

Comment: I don't know why a smaller javascript snippet would work while a longer javascript snippet would not unless there were errors in the longer snippet. If you could provide some examples on Fiddler, we might be able to diagnose further.

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `/script`.
It apears.

Do like google analitcs for instance

```
 $("#iframe").contents().find("body").append(decodeURI("**%3Cscript%3E** alert(2)  **%3C/script%3E**"));
```

replace the `script` and `/script` with this escaped ones

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, but it still doesn't make sense in my mind, please add an explanation

Comment: well.. i suppose that jQuery is doing some kind of validation with scripts.

Comment: It's not jquery, I found the problem, posting an answer

Answer (score 2):

As the iframe runs as it's own `window`, you will have to also inject the import of the jquery.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** So I played with this a bit more and here is what I came up with.

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
$("#frame").attr(
   "src", "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + 
   "<html>" + 
   "<style>.red {color: red}</style>" + 
   "<div class=\"test\">Test</test>" + 
   "<script src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js\"><" + "/script>" +    
   "<script>$(function(){ $(\".test\").addClass(\"red\")});<" + "/script>" +         
   "</html>"
);
```

This works, see here http://jsfiddle.net/WsCxj/.

So there are several points:

1. I am passing the entire content as one string. You have to prepend `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,` and then you can set your string as src of the iframe.
2. I am adding the jquery.js file *with an absolute path* - This seems to be important, presumably because the frame has no path by itself as it's content is dynamically generated.
3. I split the script end tag like this `<" + "/script>` because at least firefox tries to end the actual script at this point. The cleaner approach would probably be to have the js as totally separate file.

Comment: Hmm... Did you try building the entire content as one string and then setting it as the src attribute of the iframe?

Comment: l="<script"+" src"+"=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js\">"+"<"+"/"+"script>";
    $('#iframe_id').contents().find('body').append(l);

Comment: @Gandalf see edits, that works. You can probably take this and make it also work using your jQuery approach, but usually string building HTML is anyways faster that doing it in jQuery.

Comment: In IE9, the iframe says "The webpage cannot be displayed" error. Any reason?

Comment: IE might need a little special treatment, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504816/how-to-set-html-content-into-an-iframe-in-ie8-ie9

Answer (score 1):

You don't need add a tag script to execute javascript, you can do a function and apply iframe context...

using eval

```
function initFrame (code){

    eval (code);

}

initFrame.apply ($('#iframe').contents(),[js_code]);
```

Without eval

```
var initFrame = new Function(js_code);


initFrame.apply ($('#iframe').contents(),[]);
```

Comment: Using `new Function` is essentially the same as an eval. Running functions in the context of another frame can be problematic and hard to debug since the global object is different in both contexts...

Comment: eval can't receive a return statment, and function cannot resolve a value like (5), eval and new Function are different.

Comment: Yes they are slightly different, but in your case it doesn't matter at all. `new Function` still does an eval under the hood. Therefore, avoiding `eval` for `new Function` is not any better. `eval` may not allow a return statement, but it returns the value of the last expression evaled.

Comment: This seems to work if the content of js_code is core JavaScript. What if the content of js_code is a jQuery snippet. This does not seem to work then. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, paste following code in the page which is in an iframe, not the parent page:

```
window.myFunction = function(args) {
   alert("script from iframe");
}
```

And now add following code to call above function:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframeId");
iframe.contentWindow.myFunction(args);
```

Answer (score -2):

How about setting ajax refresh with js interval function to take any data stored in file/session etc. ?

It's surely not the most lightweight mode and it involves a tiny bit php, but can do the work.