# CodeMirror with 2 text editors and live preview?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, codemirror

I'm trying to create a live editor like jsfiddle where users can put html in `html box (textarea)` and css in `css box(textarea)` and preview the changes *live in an iframe*.

I am using `codemirror` as the editor.

So far I can only get the preview of one of the textareas in my iframe and I cannot figure out how to get the values of both textareas (css/html) and display them in my iframe exactly like jsfiddle.

This is what I have so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/vwqgtznv/

and this is my javascript code:

```
   <script>
      var delay;
      // Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
        mode: 'text/html'
      });
      editor.on("change", function() {
        clearTimeout(delay);
        //alert("hellooooo");



        delay = setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
      });

      function updatePreview() {
        var previewFrame = document.getElementById('preview');
        var preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;
        preview.open();
        preview.write(editor.getValue());
        preview.close();
      }
      setTimeout(updatePreview, 300);
    </script>

        <script>
      var delay2;
      // Initialize CodeMirror editor with a nice html5 canvas demo.
      var editor2 = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('codert'), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    matchBrackets: true,
        mode: 'text/html'
      });
      editor2.on("change", function() {
        clearTimeout(delay2);
        //alert("hellooooo");



        delay2 = setTimeout(updatePreview2, 300);
      });

      function updatePreview2() {
        var previewFrame2 = document.getElementById('preview');
        var preview2 =  previewFrame2.contentDocument ||  previewFrame2.contentWindow.document;
        preview2.open();
        preview2.write(editor2.getValue());
        preview2.close();
      }
      setTimeout(updatePreview2, 300);
    </script>
```

could someone please help me out and advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is append CSS to iframe head. Use the code below to update your iframe head for CSS.

```
function loadCSS() {
    var $head = $("#preview").contents().find("head");                
    $head.html("<style>" + editor.getValue() + "</style>");
};
```

HTML textarea should be updated with CSS. Add `loadCSS()` to your `updatePreview2()`(html textarea update function).

```
function updatePreview2() {
    var previewFrame2 = document.getElementById('preview');
    var preview2 =  previewFrame2.contentDocument ||  previewFrame2.contentWindow.document;
    preview2.open();
    preview2.write(editor2.getValue());
    preview2.close();

    // added this line
    loadCSS(); 
}
```

And when your CSS textarea changes, the preview content will be updated by `updatePreview()`(CSS textarea update function) with CSS content. It should update head only.

```
function updatePreview() {
    loadCSS();
}
```

Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/80aj9hha/), please take a demo here.

*By the way, try to name your variable and function precisely will make more people help you.*

**Update**

A clean [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/80aj9hha/71/) version.

Comment: In the demo you mentioned, the css live preview is not working. It was same as my code.

Comment: Which browser did you use? I tested in Chrome and Firefox, it both works.

Comment: The other CSS iframe is working only if we write the css code in between the <style> but it should work without style tag as well.
Please edit your code with that fix. Will accept the answer.

Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Fixed, please try again.

Comment: Great!. Thanks for the fix  and solution. Awarding the 50 reputation. 
Just one quick doubt, if I want to add javascript as third panel could you please tell me how can I do that.

Thank you

Comment: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/80aj9hha/6/). Note that `<script>` tag should not be placed in same line, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18369860/4968420).

Comment: Hey, North. Could you please help me why your Jsfiddle code is not working in codepen. I tried to figure out the problem in different editors. However, multiple languages (HTML,CSS, JavaScript) code is not working except in  Jsfiddle.
Here is the link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPXaOw

HTML with CSS is not working.

Thank you :)

Comment: It uses the jQuery library in the javascript code so you should include the jQuery library. Click the `Settings` and choose `Javascript` tab, then click `Quick-add` and choose `jQuery`. You're welcome~

Comment: Note: The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/80aj9hha/6/) shared above is really inconsistent in its naming conventions therefore makes manipulation/hacking/learning difficult. Text area for html has `id="codert"`, css has `id="code"`, js has `id="codejs"`, repetitive codemirror inits are suffixed such as html with nothing, css with `2`, javascript with `JS`. (Wait, waaat??) I tried to un-mess it so to share back a clean kick starter, but gave up. A minimal jsfiddle based on codemirror is great work, would gain from more consistency : `html`, `css`, `js`.

Comment: So I update [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/80aj9hha/71/) for better manipulation. thanks @Hugolpz feedback.

Comment: Thanks @North. Already +1-ed your answer yesterday. I will give it new try. I'am using (Ace editor so far). EDIT: I reordered HTML before CSS in the JS pad and mode: 'text/css in the CSS init. See jsfiddle.net/unsowp7a . Any idea why the syntax highlighting doesn't work ? Note: I may delete most of my comments when this issue+discussion ends. ; )

Comment: Well, I got into the CodeMirror monkey's hole a bit too much (4hours?). There is my derivation-optimization to ease reuse and hacking : https://jsfiddle.net/d3wehutq/1/ . All the sources on the top are not used. Code needs further love and cleaning, but the JS is pretty nice, well organized, and contain a good range of nice CodeMirror settings. This starts to be competitive with my current Ace.js code cleaness and features so I may compare them. ; ) Thank you North !

Comment: Your version with better comments, order https://jsfiddle.net/15p78yLj . Richer version : https://jsfiddle.net/ctba597d/5/ . The blog entry about it : https://medium.com/@hugolpz/codemirror-js-kick-starter-ba7c999e20

Answer (score 0):

Building upon @North's answer and guidance, I propose this answer. If you +1 this answer, please give +1 to North's answer as well. This is an optimization and expansion up North's anwser, building up a jsfiddle-clone. It therefor demo an answer to the question of this current page.

- [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h34n7g5p/1/) -- richer code to go further
- [Blogpost](https://medium.com/@hugolpz/codemirror-js-kick-starter-ba7c999e20) -- Medium post with some other helpers.

In .html :

```html
 <!-- load the relevant dependencies via script and style/link tags. -->
 <textarea class="code" id="editor-html">
 <textarea class="code" id="editor-css">
 <textarea class="code" id="editor-js">
```

In .js file :

```js
var editorsSettings = {
  lineWrapping: true,
  lint: true,
  lineNumbers: true,
  foldGutter: true,
  gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers","CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"],
  tabSize: 2,
  indentUnit: 2,
  matchBrackets: true
}

// Editors HTML, CSS, JS : init, bind, define settings.
let editorHTML = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector('#editor-html'), {
  mode : "htmlmixed", // require modes for xml, css, js.
  htmlMode: true,
  ...editorsSettings
});
let editorCSS = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector('#editor-css'), {
  mode: 'text/css',
  ...editorsSettings
});
let editorJS = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector('#editor-js'), {
  mode: 'text/javascript',
  ...editorsSettings
});

// Fetch and organize into results
let updatePreview = function() {
  let preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
  let previewDocument = preview.contentDocument || preview.contentWindow.document;
  previewDocument.open();
  previewDocument.write(editorHTML.getValue());
  previewDocument.write("<script>"+editorJS.getValue()+"<"+"/script>");
  previewDocument.close();
  previewDocument.querySelector('head').innerHTML = '<style>' + editorCSS.getValue() + '</style>';
}
```