# JS document.write() writes scritps into iframe's head

Tags: javascript, iframe, document.write

can someone explain me how does document.write to iframe works? I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

<script>
    var code = '<scr' + 'ipt>console.log(window.frameElement.contentWindow.document.getElementById("test") );</scr' + 'ipt><div id="test"></div>';
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.open();
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.write(code);
    document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.close();
</script>
</body>
```

Not sure how, but  tags are written to iframe's head tag, and  is written into body.
How can I get div element from inside script passed into iframe. My example doesn't work, it returns null.

Unfortunately in real life I don't know iframe's id I know only div's id.

Comment: Do you want to insert js code inside the iframe? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add JavaScript code into existing iFrame using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369410/how-to-add-javascript-code-into-existing-iframe-using-jquery)

Comment: well that code is wrong because you try to read the element before it is added.... But if the code is in the iframe, than it would be in the context of the current page so selecting the iframe makes no sense.

Comment: @epascarello My God you're right, this was so obvious I didn't see it. Creating div must be before script tag inside code var. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/85bk3cr6/1/

you can access iframe if its in the same domain as your parent page domain.If both are in the same domain you can simply acces iframe document and use write function on it.

html code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Js code:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="foo.js">\x3C/script>')
```