# How do I run JavaScript on an iframe page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know that this has supposedly been answered before, but what I want is specific.

I have a code that runs a javascript:url on the parent frame. Here's the code:

```js
javascript:W7=open('','A','width=320,height=240,resizable');W7.focus();with(W7.document){write('<title>Javascript Tester</title><center><form><textarea name=X rows=10 cols=34 wrap>javascript:</textarea><p><input type=button value=Run onclick=opener.location=X.value>');void(close())}
```

This works, but not on an iframe -- it injects to the parent. I want to inject this script into the  iframe. I can't get it to work. I tried setting Run onclick to opener.document.getElementById('myIframe').src but it didn't work. Can i get help?

Comment: you show code for a pop up window, but talking about iframe. There is no opener with iframes. There is window.parent to access the parent or you reference the parent to iframe through the iframe object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369410/how-to-add-javascript-code-into-existing-iframe-using-jquery