# make javascript/html/css editor

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a html/css/javascript online editor so I create a textarea to write the code and Iframe to display it so this is the html :

```
 <textarea id="code"></textarea>

 <iframe id="output"></iframe>

 <button id="submit-b">submit</button>
```

and this is the jquery code :

```
$("#submit-b").click(function(){
   code = $("#code").val();
   $('#output').contents().find('body').html(code);
});
```

it works to edit html and Css but not JavaScript, how can I do this?

Comment: Why not use an existing editor like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com) or something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), depending on your needs?

Comment: I want this editor not for me I want it as Graduation Project to my University so I must make it ,  I have 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/htLg9/1/).
Enter something like this in the textarea:

```
<script>alert('Boo!');</script>
```

And you will be whown a Javascript alert.

That said, why not use an existing editor like [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.com) or something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), depending on your needs?

Comment: no it didn't work with me 
in your JSFiddle example try to input a full html page like :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<p>Click the button to display the date.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
}
</script>

</body>
</html> 


this will not work

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504816/how-to-set-html-content-into-an-iframe-in-ie8-ie9

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use code mirror instead?

http://codemirror.net/

Here is sample on how this framework does it:

http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlembedded/index.html

Comment: I want this editor not for me 
I want it as Graduation Project to my University
so I must make it 
I have 3 days left 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use a pure javascript code which is it :

```
function update() 
{
var w = document.getElementById("code").value;
document.getElementById('output').contentWindow.document.write(w);
}
```

becouse jquery code append the textarea value without     `<html>` and     `<body>` tags