# Cross Origin XMLHttpRequest iFrame "Mini Browser"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to get around the  security and mimick either a full-browser or mobile browser within a webpage?

I had an idea to set the HTML manually, using an AJAX/XMLHttpRequest ("Get" request)

```
document.querySelector('#myiframe').contentWindow.document.write("<html><body>Hello
world</body></html>");
```

(from [How to set HTML content into an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504816/how-to-set-html-content-into-an-iframe-in-ie8-ie9))

Can anyone verify this is possible? I'm guessing you would lose relevant site date (cookies, cache, etc)

Comment: To do an _XMLHttpRequest_ to a different _origin_, assuming it's the same _protocol_, the server you're sending the request to needs to send the correct _CORS_ headers in the response. This is to stop you from, say, attempting to access someone's internet banking.

Comment: I'm familiar with CORS but is it really that simple? It seems arbitrary that only the top-level browser (Chrome) can use http:// protocols, but everywhere I look, people say it's not possible

Comment: It's not "simple" because it means you can't request random sites, you can only access servers you have control over. The protocol doesn't have to be _http:_, it could be _https:_ and hey if your browser permits it _file:_ or something else. The bit about the protocols is that you can't be on e.g. a _https_ resource and do an _XMLHttpRequest_ for a _http_ resource. Not sure about _CORS_ working if you try to change ports, either.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get around the security

Yes, many browsers let you start them in a security-off mode, e.g. on chrome you run the program with the `--disable-web-security` flag. However, **you should never ask a client to do this**.

An alternative way would be to write a *Java* applet, or some other third-party plugin, which fetches the resources you want and then passes it over to the browser with your favourite method, from which you can use *JavaScript* on the data as desired. This method would lose things like cookies, and might be exploitable so I wouldn't recommend it.

> mimick either a full-browser or mobile browser within a webpage?

Finally, if you don't mind the "URL bar" displaying the wrong thing when a user navigates, you could just use the default behaviour. This method is totally acceptable and doesn't circumvent any security.