# Loading a string if HTML into an iframe using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, construct-2

I have a string of HTML tags that I can add to or change whenever I like.

```
"<html><body><script language="javascript" src=""></script></body></html>"
```

Is it possible to load that string at runtime into an Iframe as if it was an HTML file?

This is for Construct 2. I have an object that can load HTML from a url fine, it can also insert HTML, and run scripts, but not as is.

Comment: Yes with data uri, it's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like javascript will not work as I'm limited by the editor to what I can input into the script.
I can add strings, just not properly formatted strings.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16557787/7794769) which uses `iframe.contentWindow.document.write("<html><body>Hello world</body></html>")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with

```
document.getElementById('iframe').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(html);
```

See the following fiddle for an example

https://jsfiddle.net/erk1e3fg/

Answer (score 7):

Sure, there are a couple of different options.

**Via `srcdoc`** (asyncronous):

```
iframe.srcdoc = html;
```

**Via data URI** (asyncronous):

```
iframe.src = 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + escape(html);
```

**Via `document.write`** (syncronous, and works in really old browsers):

```
var idoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
idoc.write(html);
idoc.close();
```

Comment: From where do you get that `srcdoc & src`  is **asyncronous**?

Comment: @stomy I'm not sure if it's technically specified somewhere that it must be either synchronous or asynchronous, but it has been my experience that srcdoc and src (even with a daraURI) are asynchronous.

Answer (score 3):

With [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), ([see browser support](http://caniuse.com/datauri)) it's possible. The format as described is

```
data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>.
```

You might not need to base64 encode your string unless the string has specific characters. This Snippet fulfills your needs:

```js
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe'),
    htmlStr = "<html><body><h1>Hell World</h1></body></html>";
iframe.src = 'data:text/html,'+htmlStr;
```

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="blank:"></iframe>
```