# how to implement device preview in web-app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flutter

I am creating similar to [snack.exop.io](https://snack.expo.io/) editor. like how are they showing phone preview on the right side? like we write something and it will show a preview of how it looks like in device, I don't even know what is this concept called, what to search really. I want to create something similar to this image.[image]

How can I add this emulator functionality in web-app.

Comment: Something similar to Virtual Network Computing.

Answer (score 2):

https://snack.exop.io uses https://appetize.io
There are pricing: https://appetize.io/pricing, but you can also try for free.

App itself runs mobile simulator on backend, and sends screenshots to front-end, that is being rendered in Canvas.
More you can read here https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8487813

Answer (score 1):

snack.expo.io uses an iFrame, probably modified using JavaScript.
Create an iFrame with no `src` (cross-origin policy applies), and use this code to modify it. [This W3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp) shows how to modify an iFrame's styles using the contentWindow property. However, I couldn't find a way to modify the content itself with that, but I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504816/how-to-set-html-content-into-an-iframe) which should help.

```
function loadFrame() {
  x = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow;
  x.document.write("<html><body>Put content here</body></html>");
}
```

However, be careful with what you allow the user to modify, since `document.write` can be a form of eval. Make sure to always escape the user's text.

Anyways, here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kvr3na9o/).