# How would an HTML page be created on the fly for an <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, parse-platform

Searching for possibilities the only viable option I found for generating an HTML file was the following snippet:

```
$file="name.html";
$fh = fopen($file, 'w'); //or w+
$stringOfHTML = "everything we want on the webpage";
fwrite = ($fh, $stringOfHTML);
```

While this is exactly what I want, it will not work within the bounds I have.  Since I'm using Parse.com I cannot host any PHP scripts, and anything that is not supported by all major browsers is immediately out of the question.

Is there anything equivalent to this, that would work with a static host like Parse.com?

E:
After looking through fsacer's response and links from those, it's become clear to me that I don't just want to dynamically interpret a string as an HTML page.

What I am looking for is to actually generate an HTML file using JavaScript(if possible) THEN set that as the iframe's source.

Comment: sorry, it is completely unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: Best option - change host

Comment: While that appears to be the best option, there's simply too much already done with other things and it isn't actually an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could put together this with ([jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)) ajax and set [src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240101/set-content-of-iframe).