# change the scr in an iframe that's in another iframe javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I change the scr of an iframe, that's in another iframe?

example: http://tomtopchina.blogspot.ro/

I want to change "what is my referer" page that's inside "mypayingcryptoads" that's inside "tomtopchina.blogspot", so can I access so deep?, it needs to be in javascript

Comment: Nope, not possible, because the first iframe is loaded from a different domain already - so the Same Origin Policy of course prevents you from accessing any of its content using client-side scripting.

Comment: Provided that you have code-access to the first iframe you could use PostMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the two

Comment: Good idea. Might not work in this case. It seems he is not in control of the first iframe...

Comment: TomTopChina + MyPayingCryptoAds = ☠

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using contents with jQuery

`let iframe = $('#some-id').contents().find('html').html()`

and then do a string replace and then write it back like

`$('#some-id').contents().find('html').html(iframeHtmlChanged)`

Pulled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240101/set-content-of-iframe)