# Redirect with a target

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script

```
<html><head><title>File Upload Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="" content=0; url="/home.html" target="link"/>
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: white;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a, .topnav input[type=text] {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfg7ZkS0TSeBbgfM4nqJCsBr-Yl3Dmrwy8UD_cXK68zYIhwjg/viewform" target="link">Upload File to Server</a>
  <!-- <a href="#">Some text...</a> -->
</div>
<iframe name="link" width="100%" height="95%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<body></html>
```

And what I want to do is make the redirect `<meta http-equiv="" content="0; url="/home.html" target="link"/>` be able to change the iframe. If I do `http-equiv="refresh"`, it just makes it reload infinitely. I have another file, home.html

```
<h1>Home</h1>
```

and I don't know how to make it autoload home.html in the iframe element. Is there a workaround, or am I just doing it wrong? If you could help, that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: If you need any other information, just leave a comment! :)

Comment: you have crucial spelling error `<meta http-equiv="" content="0; url="/home.html" target="link"/>` the `content ="0; url="` part is messing up badly... remove the content attribute. or put a " after it to close it.

Comment: @tacoshy It still doesn't work :( without the <meta http-equiv="reload" it just doesn't work

Comment: so what are you actually trying to do? you trying to load a page into an iframe? Why do you need a meta tag for it in the first place? Redirecting has to be done server sided for example with .htaccess not client bowser sided. So I gues you not actually mean a redirect

Comment: @tacoshy I'm trying to use redirect to load the iframe with home.html

Comment: @tacoshy <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url="somelink"> redirects, and links can have target="somehing" so I though that if I modified redirect it could autoload the iframe.

Comment: iframe needs a source and its not defined in the HTML head but in the iframe tag like: `<iframe src="home.html></iframe>`

Comment: @tacoshy <a href="https://google.com" target="link">google</a><iframe name="link" width="100%" height="95%" frameborder="0"></iframe> works tho?

Comment: 2 different things, that link (<a>) works as label in that case. But it not works from within the head.

Comment: @tacoshy is there another way to do it? if yes then please tell me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, close `content="0;` with a " and get rid of the semi-colon. Besides that, your question is not totally clear, but it looks like you're trying to redirect using a meta tag. I don't understand why, read this on [how to redirect using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage).

Comment: as you see in the code, there are link that change the thing in the iframe. I'm trying to make a redirection change what's in the frame to home.html.

Comment: When does the redirection take place? And do you want to update the iframe's content for every redirect?

Comment: If you're listening for an event to redirect, just change the content of the iframe directly after you redirect in the same function. This is how you change the iframe's content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240101/set-content-of-iframe