# Iframe doesn't stop to loading

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

As answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050380/set-innerhtml-of-an-iframe), I'm trying to set an Iframe's content with :

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.write("Test123");
```

The problem is that even though everything seems to work (the Iframe is displaying Test123), the browser doesn't stop loading. Indeed, in Firefox's tab it's written "Connecting ..." with the spinner indicating it's still loading.

Why does it happen ? Is there a better solution to set an Iframe's content ?

Comment: you need to close the connection: ocument.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.close(); (I think that this will work).

Comment: How exactly are you writing to contentDocument if it is supposed to be readonly? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement

Comment: Perhaps the attribute is read only but the Document that is returned is read/write. Ohh well we learn something new everyday.

Comment: @jeff : Thanks ! It works :), could you post a full answer so I can validate it as the solution.

Comment: @ars256 : I don't know exactly why, but I can confirm it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to close the iframe connection:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentDocument.close();
```

I think that this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with jQuery, it might solve your issue and it is much cleaner:

```
$("#iframe").contents().find("html").html("Test123")
```