# Need to change the iframe dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am making a simple code editor. Two panels - One to write the code and another to display the output.

For `Html` and `Css` the below code works fine. But for `javascript` which has to be executed on page load this doesn't work. When the **Update Page** button is clicked the input code must be rendered on the display frame. Like a simple `alert` on page load wont work.

My question is how should I imitate the frame `reload` action. I don't have any value for `src` attribute of the frame so cannot reload it.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function update()
{
   var x = document.getElementById('mycode').value;
   frames['display'].document.documentElement.innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

<input onclick="update();" type="button" value="Update page">
<textarea id="mycode"></textarea>
<iframe id="display"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

When this code is entered in the textarea, it wont work in the frame.

```
<html>
<script>alert(123);</script>
</html>
```

But for normal html,css it works. How should I make javascript code like above which only gets executed during pageload work in the frame?

Editor works for this kind of event driven javascript

```
<html>
<input onclick="alert(123);" type="button" value="Works">
</html>
```

Comment: javascript can access only local ifames (which has been created by your code or loaded from the same server).

Comment: @Epsil0neR When the Update Page button is clicked the code from the textarea is loaded into the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<input type="button" id = "btn" value="Update Page" />
<textarea id="mycode"></textarea>
<iframe id="display"></iframe>
```

as your HTML and

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('mycode').value;
    document.getElementById('display').contentDocument.write(x);
}
```

as your Javascript.

`contentDocument.write` is used to write an iframe's `innerHTML`.  See [set innerHTML of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050380/set-innerhtml-of-an-iframe)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/85RDH/)**