# How to change the displayed text of an input button, without changing the value of it?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I would like to change the displayed text of an input submit button from say foo, to bar. BUT I don't want to change the value. Can anyone help?

```
<input type="submit" name="random" value="foo" />
```

Comment: Is there a reason to this madness? Maybe we can help you find a better solution to whatever you are trying to work around.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you can't.  You can try this, though:

```
<button value="foo">bar</button>
```

Comment: ie < 9 will submit `bar` if this button is within the form

Comment: No thanks D: I want to keep the code I have and add code. (that's just my standpoint for this, not other issues I may have.)

Comment: @user1420493 then you can't do it with `<input>`.  Sorry!

Comment: It's okay, I just found a different way to do it with css :)

Answer (score 0):

copy paste production:

```
< script type="text/javascript" >
function replaceScript() {
    var toReplace = 'value="foo"';
    var replaceWith ='value="bar"';
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
}
< /script >
```

Then initialise in the body tag to do on page load.

```
<body OnLoad = "replaceScript();">
```

Should work fine and replace all instances in html body code.

source: [find and replace string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951801/find-and-replace-string)

Comment: This would work except there is hundreds of instances of the input buttons all with different values, I got what I needed though, and it's better than what I had planned in this question. Thanks anyways though!

Comment: Can you share what you got please?

Answer (score -1):

`<button type="submit" name="random" value="foo">bar</button>`
This work for me. Tested on Chrome and Firefox.