# Issue in Include a url in IE "Access denied"

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

I am including a page(url) in iframe in a jsp but I am getting access denied error in IE 9. However for the same , its working in chrome.

The url I have is of a 3rd party website which I need to include in iframe in my jsp page , the url has query parameters of username and password provided by me dynamically. Using these username and password , the 3rd party website makes the user login . After logging in the eventual landing page is expected to get displayed in iframe .

I want to achieve this in IE only but its failing in IE only and working for other of the browsers like chrome , firefox.

I am setting iframe in a HTML div in my jsp.

Here is the snippet of the code . I am using jquery javascript framework.

mydiv.innerHTML = <iframe name='ani' id='ani' height='800px' width='800px' src='https://x.x.x.x/a.php/?Login=abcd&Password=efgh'> /;

I just wonder when I run this code in Google chrome , its runs perfectly , only in IE this problem occurs.

Can any one please suggest me a way to achieve this or whats wrong in the method above ?

Thanks. 
P.S. I have tried including the url in Object tag instead of iframe but the behaviour is same as above i.e. its working in chrome but not in ie. 
Later I tried including another jsp as a source of iframe. in this jsp , on load I ran a dynamic form creation and submission to the url , but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357041/get-iframe-innerhtml-using-javascript) and [this forum thread](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues/118) should give you more info to find the solution/reason to/for your problem.