# innerHTML does not work with Javascript output contents

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make some kind of ads rotator as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function fillBoard() {
            s = document.getElementsByClassName('slots');
            board = document.getElementById('board');
            board.innerHTML = s[0].innerHTML
            alert(board.innerHTML);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="board" style="width:160px; text-align: center; margin:0">
    </div>

    <div class="slots" style="display:none">
        <!-- THE PROBLEM IS HERE -->
        <!-- Begin Hsoub Ads Ad Place code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            hsoub_adplace = 1310003403401506;
            hsoub_adplace_size = '125x125';
             //-->
        </script>
        <script src="http://ads2.hsoub.com/show.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- End Hsoub Ads Ad Place code -->
    </div>
    <div class="slots" style="display:none">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90/sports/1/" />
    </div>

    <div class="slots" style="display:none">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90/sports/2/" />
    </div>

    <div class="slots" style="display:none">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/160/90/sports/3/" />
    </div>

    <script>
        fillBoard();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In the code above:

1. There is a `div` with id `board` to act as a board that displays contents.
2. The board should be filled with data supplied from other hidden `divs` with class name `slots` using `innerHTML` property.
3. To do the above a function named `fillBoard()` is defined in the head section of the page and then called at the end of it just before closing `</body>` tag.

**What is happening?**

The hidden divs `slots` works fine with divs that contain images. However, in the first div there are a javascript code that should generates ads from an ads network which it does not work.

I expect that the javascript code of the ads network should fill its div with data, **then the calling** of `fillBoard()` will just copy its content to the `board` div. However, this is does not occur!

I need to know how could I overcome this issue?

*A live example is found [here](http://quran.2index.net/assets/alt_ads2.html)*

Comment: instead of `s[0].innerHTML` try `s[0]`. it's a DOM object and you should be able to append that to `boards` with `boards.append(s[0])`

Comment: @b_dubb I tried you solution, however, it returns the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'append' alt_ads2.html:16
fillBoard alt_ads2.html:16
(anonymous function)`

Comment: It can't find append because you are not using jQuery...I think b_dubb was assuming you were. The code seems to work as intended for me on Chrome. When the alert shows, the board div contains the correct dom elements including an iframe, etc. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: sorry ... native js is `board.appendChild(s[0])`

Comment: @b_dubb also this solution yielding the same as innerHTML. The javascript results does not displayed.

Comment: It seems to be the 'results' aren't displaying because there seems to be nothing in them. If I look at what ends up in board I see an iframe but it does not have any contents. Could it be that there's an error in what your show.js is producing? What are expecting as the contents?

Comment: I expect ads contents exactly like this page: http://quran.2index.net/assets/alt_ads.html

Comment: It is just alternative ads links for Google Adsense when there is no ads available by Google Ads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just show the desired hidden div and it's usually a better practice than copying DOM content. If you make sure to only show one of the hidden divs at a time you can show the image always in the same place.

Try this to show the first `"slots"` element:

```
s[0].style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: This is may be regarded as an option, if I would like to display every div in its place, However, I need to show every div content at the place of `board` div. In the case of missing any solution, I may consider your solution. Thanks.

Comment: Then you could just put the `slots` elements inside the `board` div and do just that. They would show at the place of `board`, but only the one you wanted to at any given moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after some more digging I've found the issue, although I don't have an easy solution at the moment.

The js file show.js is generating some ad content inside of an iframe for you, which you are placing in the first 'slots' div. Simple enough. When you are setting the content of the board to the content of the first slots class, an iframe is being created in the board div but without the same content.

After some searching it seems that innerHTML of an iframe will not copy the contents of the iframe if it comes from a domain other than the page domain for security reasons.

It seems to me that the solution at this point is to either show and hide the slots divs like Zhertal suggested or you can possible find some other way to physically move the content of the slots div into board, but this may still be a violation of the same security concern. I'm going to keep digging and I'll edit this answer if I find anything more.

Reference SO posts:
[Get IFrame innerHTML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357041/get-iframe-innerhtml-using-javascript)

[Javascript Iframe innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139118/javascript-iframe-innerhtml)