# How to make iframe-s scrollable on iOS (iPhone 7)

Tags: ios, iframe, scroll

iframe scroll is not working when tested on iOS. Scroll is working on Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios) will help you. The article has also an example.

Comment: will not work for me - iframes are in another iframes and I can change only parent DOM/CSS/JS

Comment: did you try it with jquery? see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490948/1534329)

Comment: Tried but failed. See example here: https://live-ssl.spongecell.com/zipped_animation/assets/1629852/original/17-04-an-formulary-coverage-300x250-final/17-04-an-formulary-coverage-300x250-final.html?wrxzyy89 (wait to text at bottom to show up).

Comment: Tried this for example:    ```$(function(){
        if (/iPhone|iPod|iPad/.test(navigator.userAgent))
            $('iframe').wrap(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                return $('<div />').css({
                    width: $this.attr('width'),
                    height: $this.attr('height'),
                    overflow: 'auto',
                    '-webkit-overflow-scrolling': 'touch'
                });
            });
    })```  - like here https://jsfiddle.net/rq7yc4to/1/

Comment: @TimofejIvajkin did you find a way to change the content?