# Display div from parent in iframe

Tags: html, jquery, kendo-ui

I'm sure this is pretty basic, but I still can't find solution that work. Basically I need to display the content in popup from parent at child.  I need to display the div 'userinfo' in window  in iframe. This is my code:

```
<!--parent.html->
<iframe src="grid-listing.html"></iframe>
<div id='userinfo'>Name:Ali</div>




<!--grid-listing.html-->


$(document).ready(function ()
{
   var windows = $('<div />').kendoWindow({
    title: "Edit user info", resizable: false, modal: true, width: 1000, 
            draggable: false,
            close: function () { this.destroy(); }
    }).data('kendoWindow').content($("#userinfo")).html());
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery changing contents of an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490907/jquery-changing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Comment: I think this one is not what i meant..

Comment: You wrote _" I need to display the div 'userinfo' in window in iframe"_ and the link I suggested shows how to change the contents of an iframe. Why is that not what you meant? Please clarify your requirements.