# Populating an iFrame.src with a string with JavaScript

Tags: iframe

I have the following line of code in my JavaScript program

```
MyFrame.src = mainPath + "/resources/help.htm";
```

This is the default but in some cases I would like to load the contents of this iFrame with a string that I build dynamically, such as:

```
"<html><head></head><body>This is additional help that was built dynamically on the fly</body></html>"
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: This question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139118/javascript-iframe-innerhtml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes:

```
MyFrame.contentWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body>This is additional help that was built dynamically on the fly</body></html>");
```