# How to switch to dynamically named iframe with Behat/Mink

Tags: iframe, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

Writing test for an iFrame generated when a button is clicked. The iFrame name and id are similar but generated dynamically. I have used "switchToiFrame" successfully before.

```html
<div class="bbbb-frame-container" style="height: 400px; width: 665px; margin-top: -200px; margin-left: -332.5px;">
<div class="user-support-frame-close-container" style="display: block;">
<div class="user-support-frame-close">Close</div>
</div>
<iframe id="poplock_default9636_priv" frameborder="0" name="poplock_default9636_priv" src="blah.blaag.com">
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

.....................

The poplock_defaultNNNN_priv is the dynamically generated iFrame that I would like to switch to..

Answer (score 9):

First, find an iframe with one of the [find methods](http://mink.behat.org/#find-methods). If it's the only iframe on the page (or the first one) use the `find() method`. If it's not, you'll have to use `findAll()` and rely on the order (since there's no distinct attribute you could search for).

Once you find your iframe, you can use [`getAttribute`](http://mink.behat.org/api/behat/mink/element/nodeelement.html#getAttribute%28%29) to get its name and then use [`switchToIframe`](http://mink.behat.org/api/behat/mink/session.html#switchToIFrame%28%29) to... well, switch to the iframe.

Comment: Just mention that links to getAttribute and swithToIframe are not working :|
Here you are an alternative link: http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/Behat/Mink/class-Behat.Mink.Driver.DriverInterface.html#_switchToIFrame

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Jakub Zalas you inspired me for testing Stripe PopUp code which is embeded into an iframe.

Just for sharing my experience on testing a Stripe Payment PopUp:

```
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame('stripe_checkout_app');
$page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

/** @var NodeElement $stripeInputField */
$stripeInputField = $page->findField($field); // where $field can be: 'Email, CVC, Card Number, MM / YY'
$emailInput->setValue($value);

// Switch Back to Main Window
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code! Btw, I had to add "--disable-site-isolation-trials" option for the Chrome browser, otherwise, it still didn't want to fill in Stripe's form in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

For whom it may help, to do the lookup for the dynamically named iframe I'm using the CSS selector on a known prefix:

```
// Switch to the payment iframe.
$iframe = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', 'iframe[name^="__privateStripeFrame"]');
$iframe_name = $iframe->getAttribute('name');
$this->getSession()->switchToIFrame($iframe_name);
```

The CSS selector `^=` refers to "starts with ..." - instead, you can use `*=` for "contains ..." if it is not a prefix.

This example is to get the Stripe 3D Secure popup.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simply manipulate the iFrame, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139118/javascript-iframe-innerhtml). The answers, for example, present Javascript to get the first iFrame so you can manipulate it:

`window.frames[0].document.body.<your action here>`

They also give jQuery examples for arbitrary iFrames:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" ...></iframe>
$('#my_iframe').contents().find('html').html();
```

While those aren't exactly what you've asked for, you *could* alter them to find the n'th iFrame, if you know the number of iFrames generated and which you'd like to manipulate, and then manipulate it as need be.