# How can I get iframe element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, parent-child

This is `main.html`

```html
<body>
    <iframe id="frame" src="frame.html"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('test').innerHtml = 'abcdefgh';
    </script>     
</body>
```

And this is `frame.html`

```
<body>
    <p id="test">0123456798</p>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Why did not work , AND how can I change `id="test"` text

Comment: I think you don't need to use `contentWindow.document`. The code should be like `document.getElementById('frame').getElementById('test').innerHtml`

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getElementById is not a function
    at

Comment: You should check value of `document.getElementById('frame')` in console that has value or not.

Comment: Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139118/javascript-iframe-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` to delay your script. The `iframe` needs time to be loaded.

```
<iframe id="frame" src="frame.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'abcdefgh';
},800);
</script>
```

And notice the capital letters on `innerHTML()`.

Comment: Hmmmm, get same result

Comment: Try a longer delay... Maybe 800 millisecond isn't enought. It depends on the iframe content.

Comment: I also tried delay 10second ^~^

Comment: It works [here](https://www.bessetteweb.com/SO/45522627/). I've set a 3000 ms delay for you to have time noticing the HTML change... But it works with 800.

Comment: yep thank you , finally it work . bcs i forgot sent file to my server , i was test it in my computer .

Comment: Great! Can you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you have a solution

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        var iframe = document.getElementById('frame');
        console.log(iframe);
    });
```

Hope it helps